# SFTP from local desktop to Solaris 11 using client tools is failing

Tags: solaris, sshd, sftp

I am trying to copy files from my local drive to Solaris 11 host using WinSCP and it is failing with the below error message:

**Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?**

I also tried SFTPing from Tectia tool and it fails with

[image]

Upon checking the logs on the server, I could see that the password is accepted for my user ID and no error message is being captured in the logs.

The sshd_config file has below entries and I suspect the presence of **-m 117** for the Subsystem is the cause of the issue. When I look at the man pages I only see -d and -u as the valid options.

So, is "-m" an invalid option and is this misconfiguration (-m option) the cause of the issue?

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -m 117

Match Group sftponly
ChrootDirectory %h
ForceCommand internal-sftp

**EDIT 1:**

Figured out that -m is a valid option on RHEL servers (man pages of sftp-server for more details).

So, it was a misconfiguration on our Solaris hosts. Removing it made SFTP connection successful.

Comment: do directory to `chroot` to  exist  (when user in sftponly group) ?

Comment: Yes, directory exists. Moreover, account that I am using to login via WinSCP isn't part of the sftponly group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as per [documentation of Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E72487/sftp-server-8.html) there is no `-m` option. I will recommend you to remove this option and restart `sshd` daemon on Solaris machine. Do not forget to keep open ssh session to the Solaris so you can correct error if `sshd` daemon do not want to restart.

Comment: Also it's quite possible that `-u 117` can replace the intended use of `-m 117` (though 007 is probably better than 117 or created directories might not be usable, unless that's the intent).

Comment: @A.B, there is such possibility, but I prefer not to speculate about :D

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thank you. Post removing the -m 117 entry from the config file, SFTP connection is going through. So, was it just incorrect option in the file blocking all incoming SFTP connections?